# Resuming application after switching to other application in WP7

Tags: multitasking, windows-phone-7

I wrote a application for windows phone 7 which search my database online and opens a link in Internet explorer by `WebBrowserTask`. When the internet explorer opens my application minimizes which is usual thing to happen.

And when i get back to my application which is running in the background it shows a message "*Resuming*" and my application is started from the beginning. The changes made is gone.(The search results)

How to preserve these changes when the application is running in the background, when Multitasking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a windows phone 7 application how do I make sure it supports fast task switching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099861/i-have-a-windows-phone-7-application-how-do-i-make-sure-it-supports-fast-task-swi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I answered this question over at this question:

> [I have a windows phone 7 application how do I make sure it supports fast task switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099861/i-have-a-windows-phone-7-application-how-do-i-make-sure-it-supports-fast-task-swi/7100454#7100454).

Check that out and let me know if it meets your needs.